# Redirecting HTTP to HTTPS on 403 - why returning with 403 status code?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, dom-events, iis-6

IIS 6.0 - I have checked the "Require secure channel (SSL)" check-box.

On HTTP request - it is generating the 403 error and on custom error, I am redirecting same request to HTTPS.

```
var httpURL = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL ;
window.location = httpsURL ;
```

Below is the Javascript content:

```
<!-- beginning of HttpRedirect.htm file -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectToHttps() {
    var httpURL = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL ; window.location = httpsURL ; } 
redirectToHttps();
 </script>
 <!-- end of HttpRedirect.htm file -->
```

When there is HTTP request we can redirect to HTTPS, and if we are redirecting then status code should 200

On response still it is retuning 403 as status code. Can change it to 200 (OK) - Status code as we have handled the 403 **in "Javascript"**

IIS Log:-

> 2013-10-01 23:59:45 W3SVC1 IP GET / - 80 - IP - 302 0 0
> 2013-10-01 23:59:50 W3SVC1 IP GET / - 80 - IP - 302 0 0
> 2013-10-01 23:59:55 W3SVC1 IP GET / - 80 - IP - 302 0 0

Comment: I understood everything up to the javascript.  Where is that javascript?  If you are issuing an http redirect, then there is no chance for any javascript to execute.  What do you mean by "Can change it to 200 (OK)"?  Is that a statement or a question?  What is your question?

Comment: Below is the javascript content                                  <!-- beginning of HttpRedirect.htm file -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectToHttps()
{

var httpURL = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
var httpsURL = "https://" + httpURL ;
window.location = httpsURL ;
}
redirectToHttps();
</script>
<!-- end of HttpRedirect.htm file -->                                                                          When there is HTTP request we can redirect to HTTPS. and if we are redirecting then status code should 200

Comment: What http code do you get when you navigate directly to the https url?

Comment: IIS Log:- 2013-10-01 23:59:45 W3SVC1 IP GET / - 80 - IP - 302 0 0
2013-10-01 23:59:50 W3SVC1 IP GET / - 80 - IP - 302 0 0
2013-10-01 23:59:55 W3SVC1 IP GET / - 80 - IP - 302 0 0

Comment: If I unchecked the "Require secure channel (SSL)" check-box in IIS then site is running okay on HTTPS